# I am not able to understand the meaning of following sentence. Please help me understand if it is a statement of question.

Tags: word-choice, phrases, syntactic-analysis, questions

*May I submit that my educational background, research and employment experience, and a diverse skill set make me a good fit for your academic program.
*
I read this sentence in a Statement of Purpose. Please help me understand if it sounds like a question or it is just a style of writing using the 'May I' prefix. 
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question, the subject is just remarking that all his qualifications would be suitable for whatever situation this is taking place. (In this case, this appears to be part of some sort of letter of motivation to enrol in a certain programme).

"May I submit that" here could be seen as  "If I may point it out myself" or something like that, it's to reinforce some other previous statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hiago, actually, it's my Statement of Intent, the last line was suggested by my senior, but I couldn't undertand it. So posted it here. Thanks. As i have less points, i cannot upvote, i wish i could. :-)

Comment: +1 Personally, as a native BrE speaker, I see "_May I submit..._" as overly formal and somewhat self-deprecating. However, it might be that Statements of Intent/Purpose in your field are expected to read like that, so seek other views before discarding it. For a closing sentence in such circumstances, _I_ would probably have gone for either "_I believe that..." or "_Finally, I believe that..._".

Comment: @TripeHound I agree with you, I am considering to change it. Thanks for the suggestion. Initially I went with `Therefore, I am confident that ....`. What do you think about it? If you think it's not good, I may just take up with `I believe that ..' Thanks

Comment: "_Therefore_" could also work. Although – because it is the linking word between an argument and its conclusion – you probably should make sure that the immediately preceding paragraphs were arguing/demonstrating the quality of you educational background, research experience etc. (With, say, "_Finally, I believe that..._" you would still need those paragraphs, but you _could possibly_ have talked of other things in between.

Comment: The purpose of the sentence is to make a statement, politely, but the sentence is phrased as a question. Questions require a question mark. I agree with the suggestions from @TripeHound to rewrite, avoiding a question mark at the end of your statement of intent.